# Dynamic array of pointers, how to do it correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I know, I could use std::vector or something like that, but I want to know where I think wrong. In the example below, only p3 is in my eyes really a pointer to an array of pointers and is used in the way I would expect. Using p1 instead looks kind of wrong to me because it looks like p1 is also an array of pointers like p2 is and not a pointer to an array of pointers, except for the delete thing. So when I try to use p2 as I do use p3:

`(*p2)[i] = new Foo(i);`

the error is:

`ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Foo’ and ‘Foo*’)`

The question is:

1. Why do I have to use a cast in the line where p3 is allocated?
2. Is that assignment for p3 correct or does it just work by incident?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
 public:
   Foo (int key)
      : key(key)
   {}

   int show() const
   {
      return key;
   }

 private:
   int key;
};

int main (int, char**)
{
   int aSize = 10;
   using FooP = Foo *;

   FooP *p1 = new FooP[aSize];
   FooP p2[aSize];
   FooP (*p3)[] = (FooP (*)[]) new FooP[aSize];

   for (int i=0; i < aSize; i++)
   {
      p1[i] = new Foo(i);
      p2[i] = new Foo(i + aSize);
      (*p3)[i] = new Foo(i + aSize * 2);
   }

   for (int i=0; i < aSize; i++)
   {
      cout << p1[i]->show() << ", "
           << p2[i]->show() << ", "
           << (*p3)[i]->show()
           << endl;

      delete p1[i];
      delete p2[i];
      delete (*p3)[i];
   }
   cout << endl;

   delete [] p1;
   delete [] p3;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't this line: `FooP *p1 = new FooP[aSize];` not declare a pointer to an array of pointers in your eyes?

Comment: The reason is explained quite clear in the next reported error: "invalid user-defined conversion from ‘Foo*’ to ‘const Foo&’".

Comment: @RoQuOTriX If p1 is a pointer to an array of pointers, why is the statement (*p1)[0]->show() wrong then?

Comment: @exprosic: Where do you see that error?

Comment: @user12457187 I saw it when I compile a copy of your code with the modification you have suggested ("try to use p2 as I do use p3"), with g++ 9.3.0

Comment: OK, so if p1 is a pointer to an array of pointers, *p1 has to be an array of pointers. But why is then (*p1)[0] **not** a pointer?

Comment: @user12457187 p1 is NOT a pointer to an array of pointers (`*(*)[]`). It is a pointer to a pointer (`**`), to which an array of pointers (`*[]`) is sometimes coerced.

Comment: @exprosic That's clear to me and leads me to question again why the statement: new FooP[aSize] does not return a pointer to an array of pointers, as I would expect, but has to be casted. And is this cast correct or could it lead to problems?

Comment: @user12457187 That's just the rule. "The new-expression returns a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, **if an array of objects was constructed, a pointer to the initial element of the array.** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)" So there is no cast. It's just a special case of the new expression.

Answer (score 0):

So the explanation is, that the operator "new" in case of an array, always returns a pointer to the first element and not, as I expected, a pointer to the array of pointers.

So the cast I used when assigning the allocated memory to the variable p3 is valid and would not cause any memory corruption, right?

Thanks to @exprosic for the helpful hint in the comments to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Quote from there:

*The new expression attempts to allocate storage and then attempts to construct and initialize either a single unnamed object, or an unnamed array of objects in the allocated storage. The new-expression returns a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, if an array of objects was constructed, a pointer to the initial element of the array.*